# How to delete rows in other database tables

Tags: sql

I have 4 db tables below which all in common contains the `SessionId` field either as a foreign or primary key: (The tables shown below are not the full tables, just a shortened version for you to see)

**Session Table:**

```
SessionId (PK) SessioName
1              AAA
2              AAB
```

**Session_Completed Table**

```
SessionId (PK) Complete
1              0
2              1
```

**Question Table**

```
SessionId (PK) QuestionId(PK) (Composite Keys)
1              1
1              2
2              1
2              2
```

**Answer Table**

```
AnswerId(PK) SessionId(FK)  QuestionId
   1              1          1
   2              1          1
   3              1          2
   4              2          1
   5              2          2
   6              2          2
```

My question is that is it possible that if a `SessionId` in the `Session_Completed` table is deleted from the database, then delete rows in all of the other tables where it contains the same `SessionId`?

I also want to do the same thing if a `SessionId` is deleted from the `Session` Table.

Thanks

Comment: when you delete from Session_Completed table at that time also delete from other tables by that SessionId

Comment: In foreign key, you can only refer to either Session or Session_Completed. So in one case you have do delete manually.

Comment: Instead of manually deleting, he could use a trigger. What Database is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add ON DELETE CASCADE to your foreign key constraints.

First, drop the current constraint without a cascading delete.

```
ALTER TABLE Session_Completed
DROP PRIMARY KEY pk_SessionId
```

Then, re-add the constraint with the ON DELETE CASCADES:

```
ALTER TABLE Session_Completed
  add CONSTRAINT fk_sessionid
    FOREIGN KEY (SessionId)
    REFERENCES session(SessionId)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: true.....but how are you going to delete data when SessionId is deleted from two tables Session and Session_Completed? In foreign key you can refer to either Session or Session_Completed.

Comment: I would think that the OP should change his schema.  I would think SessionId should be a primary key in one table and a foreign key everywhere else.

Comment: I think you need one sessionid primary key, then you can use ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: How bout this, can I use ON DELETE CASCADE for when the user has deleted as `SessionId` from `Session` Table only and that is able to delete the `SessionId` in all the other tables?

Comment: @JohnBrodie Can I ask how to add ON DELETE CASCADE to a foriegn key constrait, can you show an example in your answer plz

Comment: @user1830984 Edited in above.

Comment: @JohnBrodie Thanks so this means that if SessionId in `Session` Table is deleted, then it deletes the same id in Session_Completed? To do it for other tables I just need to include the above code but obviously change the table names?

Comment: Yes, which seems to be the behavior you are after.  You'll need to keep SessionId a primary key in the session table, and make it a foreign key everywhere else, using the same constraint (with the names substituted in as appropriate).  To add the FK constraints to the other tables, you'll first have to drop them.